# DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet not serving port 80

Tags: ubuntu, port, python

I have a simple Python server on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu droplet that should serve the index.html file in the /dist folder:

```
port = 8000
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dist'))
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', port), Handler)
print('Serving at port ', port)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I have no cloud firewalls running on this box. I ran 'sudo ufw allow 80/tcp' to open the firewall and if I run ufw status it shows port 80 as being open to everybody. I ran 'sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000' to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 8000.

If I run nmap from another box, the only open port is ssh on 22. Port 80 is filtered. Navigating to the host in my browser results in a connection timeout. Trying to serve directly from port 80 yields the same results. If I try nmap or netstat locally, the port shows open but the server crashes (connection reset by peer, no other useful error info). What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to enable the DigitalOcean firewall and set it up, otherwise it was just blocking all non-ssh connections.

Answer (score 0):

Run

> ufw allow 8000/tcp

to enable port 8000. (If you want to use port 80 replace 8000 by 80.)

If this does not work you **might** need to force the change. (Never had to use that until now.)

#### Reason for this

Even if no external firewall is configured Ubuntu is configured to allow only ssh (and maybe other ports depending on the base image you have chosen).